# SQL: swap two to-from (directional) columns into two unidirectional columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, graph-theory

I am dealing with some graph related data, which has directional to-from nodes. This is the initial mock data.

[image]

However, I am trying to analyse it as unidirectional path. This means that I will somehow need to swap some of the rows of node1 with node2 to do a group by. Like below.

[image]

Does anyone know how to write an SQL query for this? Thanks!

heres the mock initial data in comma delimited.

```
id,node1,node2,count
1,A,B,10
2,B,A,20
3,C,B,30
4,C,A,30
5,A,C,20
6,B,C,10
```

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apparently want the smaller value to be node1. This can be done using the `least()` and `greatest()` functions:

```
select id, 
       least(node1, node2) as node1, 
       greatest(node1, node2) as node2,
       "count"
from the_table;
```